# How to import data from ascii file into a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, import, ascii

I don't know how to import data from ASCII file into a vector.
Here is my data look like:[image]

42019*1 3738.937 21*1 3413.974 20*1 3439.52 3287.071 20*1 3078.413 3144.528 20*1 2695.402 2817.517 20*1 2360.609 2535.899 20*1 1973.107 2423.964 20*1 1853.081 2405.671 20*1 1910.165 2377.648 20*1 2003.988 2587.324 21*1 2756.768 21*1 2759.812 21*1 2751.675 21*1 2805.15 21*1 2860.665 21*1 2977.085 21*1 3095.787 10473*1 4208.778 21*1 4263.975 21*1 4409.382 21*1 4576.375 21*1 4310.54 21*1 3995.481 3698.043 20*1 3501.637 3549.6 20*1 3080.588 3484.296 20*1
 2809.161 3449.817 20*1 2584.879 3279.022 4782.676 19*1 2242.631 3180.007 4912.585 19*1 2150.003 3198.538 4964.336 19*1 2453.268 3326.228 4950.596 19*1 2572.416 3600.228 5072.902 19*1 2561.87 4009.568 5311.883 19*1 2778.983 4139.855 5447.728 19*1 2934.39 4152.131 5349.623 19*1 2914.206 4217.744 5426.702 19*1 2842.173 4228.848 5542.386 19*1 2729.679 3995.736 5315.139 19*1 2791.181 3939.073 4855.432 19*1 2906.625 4063.82 4518 3243.637 18*1 2804.122 4068.833
 4339.896 3472.643 18*1 2873.355 4011.656 4219.517 3815.508 18*1 3177.821 4065.067 4017.852 4094.735 18*1 3523.447 4123.344 3912.661 4196.315 18*1 3657.643 4033.419 3906.543 4135.803 18*1 3692.156 3850.777 3795.754 3977.24 18*1 3689.029 3866.12 3570.128 3656.568 18*1 3631.752 3889.502 3514.744 3369.104 18*1 3511.714 3689.989 3705.094 3226.042 18*1 3430.077 3366.809 3930.563 3212.605 18*1 3404.816 3195.999 3901.077 3133.576 18*1 3373.697 3086.668 3754.917
 3014.06 18*1 3264.212 2988.194 3597.519 2922.759 18*1 3248.592 2898.228 3355.479 2799.94 18*1 3344.334 2835.604 2973.876 2693.686 18*1 3286.128 2817.112 2689.906 2621.489 16*1 4764.407 1 3171.498 2770.62 2608.038 2584.703 16*1 4462.878 1 3203.648 2696.728 2506.159 2577.2 16*1 4122.297 1 3148.35 2680.205 2488.023 2603.228 15*1 4091.906 3782.092 1 2984.83 2694.59 2631.974 2647.052 15*1 3780.004 3512.631 1 2905.647 2722.086 2701.115 2732.39 15*1 3617.159

Please noted that 42019*1 means 1 was repeated 42019 times. There is no columns, just one column.

I've tried parse.SAScii and read.SASciifunction, but there is an error:

```
parse.SAScii("text2.data", beginline = 2)

x <- read.SAScii("text2.data", beginline = 2)

Error in if (max(asterisk_slash) < 0) SASinput[j] <- "" else SASinput[j] <- sub(substr(SASinput[j],  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: I might be confused, but is your file an ASCII file (as in, just text) or is it a file that came from SAS?

Comment: Thank you, Joran! It's a ASCII file. I'm trying to upload the data. Can you give me a hint how to upload data?

Comment: Ok, I think you've latched onto this particular function just because it has the word "ascii" in it, but I don't think you've looked carefully at it's documentation. It appears that function is for parsing special SAS files, not text data files. Typically we would read data into R using functions like `read.table` but the specifics of how you do that depend on the structure of your file, which you haven't described at all. Edit your question to include that information. Comma delimited? Tab delimited? etc.

Comment: I did as you asked. Any clue?

Comment: So if you opened the file in a text editor, the values would all appear in a single column and the first entry would literally be `42019*1`?

Comment: Check it out what my data look like. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm considering the output you want is a vector where cases like 42019*1 turn into rep(1,4209) and cases like 3738.937 stay the same.

If that's it, this is an option:

```
string = "42019*1 3738.937 21*1 3413.974 20*1 3439.52 3287.071 20*1 3078.413 3144.528 20*1 2695.402 2817.517 20*1 2360.609 2535.899 20*1 1973.107 2423.964 20*1 1853.081 2405.671 20*1 1910.165 2377.648 20*1 2003.988 2587.324 21*1 2756.768 21*1 2759.812 21*1 2751.675 21*1 2805.15 21*1 2860.665 21*1 2977.085 21*1 3095.787 10473*1 4208.778 21*1 4263.975 21*1 4409.382 21*1 4576.375 21*1 4310.54 21*1 3995.481 3698.043 20*1 3501.637 3549.6 20*1 3080.588 3484.296 20*1 2809.161 3449.817 20*1 2584.879 3279.022 4782.676 19*1 2242.631 3180.007 4912.585 19*1 2150.003 3198.538 4964.336 19*1 2453.268 3326.228 4950.596 19*1 2572.416 3600.228 5072.902 19*1 2561.87 4009.568 5311.883 19*1 2778.983 4139.855 5447.728 19*1 2934.39 4152.131 5349.623 19*1 2914.206 4217.744 5426.702 19*1 2842.173 4228.848 5542.386 19*1 2729.679 3995.736 5315.139 19*1 2791.181 3939.073 4855.432 19*1 2906.625 4063.82 4518 3243.637 18*1 2804.122 4068.833 4339.896 3472.643 18*1 2873.355 4011.656 4219.517 3815.508 18*1 3177.821 4065.067 4017.852 4094.735 18*1 3523.447 4123.344 3912.661 4196.315 18*1 3657.643 4033.419 3906.543 4135.803 18*1 3692.156 3850.777 3795.754 3977.24 18*1 3689.029 3866.12 3570.128 3656.568 18*1 3631.752 3889.502 3514.744 3369.104 18*1 3511.714 3689.989 3705.094 3226.042 18*1 3430.077 3366.809 3930.563 3212.605 18*1 3404.816 3195.999 3901.077 3133.576 18*1 3373.697 3086.668 3754.917 3014.06 18*1 3264.212 2988.194 3597.519 2922.759 18*1 3248.592 2898.228 3355.479 2799.94 18*1 3344.334 2835.604 2973.876 2693.686 18*1 3286.128 2817.112 2689.906 2621.489 16*1 4764.407 1 3171.498 2770.62 2608.038 2584.703 16*1 4462.878 1 3203.648 2696.728 2506.159 2577.2 16*1 4122.297 1 3148.35 2680.205 2488.023 2603.228 15*1 4091.906 3782.092 1 2984.83 2694.59 2631.974 2647.052 15*1 3780.004 3512.631 1 2905.647 2722.086 2701.115 2732.39 15*1 3617.159"
splitted = as.list(strsplit(string," ")[[1]])

for(i in 1:length(splitted)){
  if(grepl("*",splitted[[i]],fixed=T)){
    aux = strsplit(splitted[[i]],"*",fixed=T)[[1]]
    splitted[[i]] = rep(as.numeric(aux[2]),as.numeric(aux[1]))
  }
  else{
    splitted[[i]] = as.numeric(splitted[[i]])  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My data is in a *.data file. How can I import them into a single string?

Comment: Using R I'm not sure. You could try `read.table()` and see what kind of data gets imported. Hard to tell without the file.

Comment: I was inspired by your thought and found the solution:

data <- vector()  
splitted <- scan("text2.data",what="",skip=1,quiet=TRUE)

for(i in 1:length(splitted)){
  if(grepl("*",splitted[[i]],fixed=T)){  
    aux <- strsplit(splitted[[i]],"*",fixed=T)[[1]]
    data1 <- rep(as.numeric(aux[2]),as.numeric(aux[1]))
  }
  else{
    data1 = as.numeric(splitted[[i]])  
  }
  data <- c(data, data1)
}